# How to restore from a mercurial backup

Tags: mercurial

I created a backup of my mercurial repository using

```
hg bundle --all name.hg
```

Now, how would i restore my repository using the backup file? Say if my whole repository is corrupted and all i have is just this *.hg file., Is it possible to restore my repository(assuming that is what backup is supposed to be for., but did i miss any step while backing up the repository ?)

Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To quote the help page:

> The bundle file can then be transferred using conventional means
>       and applied to another repository with the unbundle or pull
>       command. This is useful when direct push and pull are not
>       available or when exporting an entire repository is undesirable.

So you would be creating a new empty repository and pull from your backup file.

```
hg unbundle [-u] FILE...

apply one or more changegroup files

    Apply one or more compressed changegroup files generated by the
    bundle command.

options:

 -u --update  update to new tip if changesets were unbundled
```

Note that you can also use regular file system tools to backup your repository. Bundles are useful when you need to transfer a set of changes somewhere else (or when disk space for the backup is an issue, because they are compressed and smaller than the on-disk repo itself).

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is simply using `hg clone`:

```
hg clone name.hg name/
```